# Constructor not found when testing smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rust, testing

I am implementing a project using the directory structure proposed by openbrush.
The contract compiles without a problem, but when it comes to testing I run
into the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for trait object `dyn project_name::traits::traitName::TraitName` in the current scope
   --> tests/integrations_tests.rs:148:30
    |
148 |             let contract = TraitName::new(input);
    |                              ^^^ function or associated item not found in `dyn project_name::traits::traitName::TraitName`
```

Do I need to declare the constructor in the trait somewhere?

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![feature(min_specialization)]

#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod name {
    use project_name::traits::traitName::*;
  
    impl TraitName {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(input: bool) -> Self {
            ink_lang::codegen::initialize_contract(|contract: & mut Self| {
                Self::new_init(contract, input)
            })
        }

        fn new_init(&mut self, input: bool) {
            // do smth with input
        }
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use super::*;
        use ink_lang as ink;

        #[ink::test]
        fn test_nr_1(){
            let contract = TraitName::new(true);
            // stuff to test with contract
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of contract you want to test? the new function (or ink constructor) should be inside the implementation of the contract storage struct

Comment: Sure, sry about that. I adjusted the error message and provided an example how I structured my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to the problem was to not have the tests in a seperate test module.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![feature(min_specialization)]

#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod name {
    use project_name::traits::traitName::*;
  
    impl TraitName {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(input: bool) -> Self {
            ink_lang::codegen::initialize_contract(|contract: & mut Self| {
                Self::new_init(contract, input)
            })
        }

        fn new_init(&mut self, input: bool) {
            // do smth with input
        }
    }

    
    use ink_lang as ink;

    #[ink::test]
    fn test_nr_1(){
        let contract = TraitName::new(true);
        // stuff to test with contract
    }
        
}
```